# Charge and negative current

Tags: current, charge

Consider the following charge-time graph :

[image]

If we need to calculate the current in the interval 8 to 12 seconds the current will be negative (since the current is the differentiation of the charge with respect to time , that is the slope of the graph and in this interval the slope is -ve) , so what is the physical meaning behind this negative current or what has happens to the charges to make the current negative in this interval ? According to my understanding the negative current means that the current is in an opposite direction but here the charge has decreased so how this is related to this negative current ?

Comment: 3 stages: Charge>Float> Discharge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increase is the capacitor charging up. The decrease or negative current is the capacitor discharging which is why the current is decreasing.

The horizontal line is the time that the capacitor holds the charge for before it discharges.

The job of a capacitor is to store charge/energy in a electrostatic field between two plates.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the physical meaning behind this negative current or what has happens to the charges to make the current negative in this interval ?

A negative current is a current flowing in the opposite direction from whichever direction you decided positive current flows in.

If this graph is about charge on a capacitor plate, then positive current is current that flows in to the plate from some source, and negative current is current that flows away from the plate.

Comment: *A negative current is a current flowing in the opposite direction from whichever direction you decided positive current flows in.* Things aren't difficult if you keep them simple! I like tautologies!